# Default Values in Oracle Functions

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Assume the following function declaration:

```
FUNCTION ARTTEXTJN
(p_art_id     in number
,p_arttextart in varchar2 default 'basis'
,p_sprache    in varchar2 default null
,p_aufart     in number   default null
,p_fallback_arttextart in varchar2  default 'J' 
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
```

Expect the first parameter all parameter have a default value.

jOOQ generate a package method like this:

```
public static Field<String> arttextjn(Field<? extends Number> pArtId, Field<String> pArttextart, 
              Field<String> pSprache, Field<? extends Number> pAufart, Field<String> pFallbackArttextart) {
    Arttextjn f = new Arttextjn();
    f.setPArtId(pArtId);
    f.setPArttextart(pArttextart);
    f.setPSprache(pSprache);
    f.setPAufart(pAufart);
    f.setPFallbackArttextart(pFallbackArttextart);
    return f.asField();
}
```

If I want to use it in a query I have to pass null to the function:

```
dsl.select(KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNR, KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNRKAMP,
           PaBez.arttextjn(KAMPARTIKEL.ART_ID, null, null, null, null))
```

But then Oracle does not use the default values.

Is there a way to tell jOOQ to generate overloaded methods with all possible combinations? Otherwise I'm not able to use that function in a select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell jOOQ to generate overloaded methods with all possible combinations?

No, there would be way too many combinations. Of course, you could extend the code generator yourself, but I would advise against it.

> Otherwise I'm not able to use that function in a select clause.

Yes, you can use it! But not using that auxiliary method `PaBez.arttextjn`. It's possible to call it as a standalone function call:

```java
Arttextjn f = new Arttextjn();
f.setPArtId(1);
f.execute();
String result = f.getReturnValue();
```

It should be possible to use in a SQL statement as well:

```
Arttextjn f = new Arttextjn();
f.setPArtId(KAMPARTIKEL.ART_ID);

var result =
dsl.select(KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNR, KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNRKAMP, f.asField())
   .from(KAMPARTIKEL)
   .fetch();
```

In your case, this should work out of the box.

Note that as of jOOQ 3.11, and in Oracle, jOOQ passes function arguments by index in this case, not by name (as it does for PostgreSQL). The generated SQL is:

```sql
select KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNR, KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNRKAMP, pa_bez.arttextjn(KAMPARTIKEL.ART_ID)
from KAMPARTIKEL
```

Which works because you're using only the first parameter, applying defaults to the rest. It wouldn't work if you would pass the last parameter, in case of which the generated SQL would have to use named parameters:

```sql
select 
  KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNR, 
  KAMPARTIKEL.ARTNRKAMP, 
  pa_bez.arttextjn(p_art_id => KAMPARTIKEL.ART_ID)
from KAMPARTIKEL
```

I've created an issue to fix this for jOOQ 3.12:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8560

Comment: Thank you this solves our problem already because we usually use the first parameters but the version from 3.12 will be even better!

Comment: Generally, when overloading a method with optional parameters, you can declare several methods in its place, each one having rightmost optional parameters. For *n* parameters, where all but the first parameter is optional, the first method has one optional parameter (the rightmost), the next method has two optional parameters (the rightmost two), and so on, for a total of *n* − 1 overloaded methods. This reduces the number of combinations of overloaded methods.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: Thanks for your enlightenment. I don't think it would make sense to generate overloaded methods in the jOOQ API as you're suggesting. In general, in PL/SQL, named and defaulted parameters are often used in a similar way as you'd use a map or properties in Java. From my experience, the assumption that the right most parameters are significantly more likely to be left out is wrong. YMMV of course.