# Call a function with default value in an SQL statement

Tags: java, jooq

I have this SQL statement:

```
select pa_bez.divlovs(lovart, lovid) bez, lovid, lovart from divlovs where lovart = ?
```

`pa_bez.divlovs` has a third parameter with a default value.

jOOQ generated this method:

```
public static Field<String> divlovs(String pLovart, String pLovid, String pSprache)
```

If I use this in the SELECT statment I'll have to pass null and the default value will not used.

How can I translate this query to jOOQ that `pa_bez.divlovs` is called with only two parameters?

Comment: [See also this question ;-)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55810226/521799)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `static` convenience method if you want to apply the default, you'll have to use the underlying `Routine` object, e.g.

```java
Divlovs divlovs = new Divlovs();
divlovs.setPLovart(...);
divlovs.setPLovid(...);

List<String> result =
ctx.select(divlovs.asField())
   .from(DIVLOVS)
   .where(DIVLOVS.LOVART.eq(...))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Nooooo! I'm getting old and lazy. Thank you

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: This is a good reminder to finally give stored procedures a bit more love in the manual! (E.g. https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5678). I mean, there should be an entire section dedicated to default parameter values. Also, usually, when writing more manual sections, new, improved API is discovered through "dogfooding". So, no worries. I consider your question as a hint that the documentation is insufficient!